# How to read / write ASCII .pgm file

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, file-io, pgm

I am new to filing and have not much idea about it.

I have written a code that tries to read an ASCII .pgm file named `owl.pgm` and writes it as `myowl.pgm` file:

```
#include <fstream>
const int MAXHEIGHT=221;
unsigned char *bitmap[MAXHEIGHT]={'\0'} ;// pointers to each pixel row
int main()
{
    int width=201, height=221;
    std::ifstream ifile("owl.pgm",std::ios::in);
    std::ofstream ofile("myowl.pgm",std::ios::out);
    for(int i=0;i<height;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<width;++j)
            ifile.read(bitmap[i][j],sizeof(bitmap));
    }
    ofile << "P2\n" << width << " " << height << "\n255\n";
    for(int i=0;i<height;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<width;++j)
            ofile<<bitmap[i][j];
    }
}
```

By my code has some errors. I will be thankful if anybody help me in correcting it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the way you read pixels from input file:

```
std::ifstream ifile("owl.pgm",std::ios::in);
for(int i=0;i<height;++i)
{
    for(int j=0;j<width;++j)
        ifile.read(bitmap[i][j],sizeof(bitmap));
}
```

**Problem 1**: You need to make sure your program doesn't treat the header of this file as actual pixels of the image. See the header format of [PGM](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ppm/). You'll most likely have to skip first 3 lines before reading the pixels.

**Problem 2**: You are trying to read whole bitmap at once, but you do that within a nested loop that was obviously meant to read the bitmap pixel by pixel.

Reading of pixels could look like this instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        ifile >> bitmap[i][j];
}
```

Comment: I got an error when my program executes."Unhandled exception at 0x00418019 in owl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000." I have changed code as your suggestion. Do you now help me in resolving this error.

Comment: @zorroz: Hard to tell what exactly is the problem here. With my answer I just wanted to point out that you should consider the header before reading the actual data + showed a possible approach that would give you the right direction. In case you are stuck with this access violation and can't get it work, then post it as a new question :)